# Look for tables in a subdirectory

Tags: database, delphi, bde

Using BDE and TTable components that run off of alias' how do I navigate from the alias into a sub directory?

For example I have an alias 'GIPM' this alias points to 'C:\Program Files\GIPM' within this directory I have another directory that contains more tables that I want to use but don't want in the directory that GIPM points to.

I have tried putting 'GIPM\SubDir' as the database but that doesn't work, I have also tried '.\SubDir' and this also does not work, do I have to create a second alias or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that was incorrect. Paradox, including support by the BDE was able to deal with tables in subdirectories quite easily. Just refer to the table as Subdir\tablename. It already knows from your alias that you are starting in c:\program files\gipm.

Answer (score 2):

From the fact that your GPIM alias points to a folder, I am inferring that you are using dbf or paradox tables. With those the concept of a "database" really isn't anything more than a folder and a different folder would be a different database.

As such, the BDE only knows/has/supports a single folder as the database. Subfolders are an unknown concept in this respect. As a matter of fact, I couldn't come up with an analogy of such a subfolder in any "real" relational database.

So in short: yes, you will have to create a second alias.